# How to do not call subscribe() body on the second time after Fragment rotation?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have an `Fragment`, that contains `Presenter`. 
Each time when user moving app to background, or make suspend\resume of the phone my logic in `Presenter` calls automatically, because I detaching and attaching presenter in `onResume()` and in `onPause()` methods to make Presenter sleep, when user do not intercating with screen. The questions is : is it possible to resubscribe Observable, but do not call `subscribe()` body for the first time? Because now each time when I rotating the device I see loading indicator, then I do not want to see it.

Pseudocode:

Fragment :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    graphPresenter.attach(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    graphPresenter.detach(this);
}
```

Presenter :

```
@Override
protected void onAttach(View view) {

final Observable<Data> dataObservable = 
        dataRepository.getDataIdentifier()
                .switchMap(id -> {

                    //this calls each time on rotation =(

                    view.showDataLoading();
                    return repository.loadData(id);
                });

    dataObservable.subscribe(data -> {
           view.showData(data);
           view.hideDataLoading();
    });
}
```

My data loading not so often, so I don't want to see loading indicator. Just want to see old data immediately after rotation.

P.S. I tried to set `setRetainInstance(true)` but it wasn't helps.

Answer (score 0):

Method `setRetainInstance` used for other goals - it's used for saving instance of fragment between activity re-creating (when configuration changed).

In your case maybe best way it's to create flag in presenter, which denotes, that data is loaded:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(View view) {
    if (!isDataLoaded) {
        dataRepository.getData()
                .doOnSubscribe(d -> view.showLoading(true))
                .doAfterTerminate(d -> view.showLoading(false))
                .doOnSuccess(d -> isDataLoaded = true)
                .subscribe(view::showData, Throwable::printStackTrace);
    }
}
```

Also, you can call `attach` method not in `onResume`, but in `onCreate`, as I understand it will not lead to errors.